# GCP Pubsub - protobuf message - Timestamp - Read issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, protobuf-java

This is regarding GCP Pubsub and reading protobuf messasge from subscribed topic.
Problem: What we observed that GCP's Unary Pull Java API not able to read messages (especially which has protobuf.timestamp datatype in it) properly whereas StreamPull API is able to read without any issues. Difference in APIs should be in reading the message either in synchronous way or in async but should not have any impact on reading the message content (bytes). Any clues there is a issue in reading protobuf.timestamp related messages? Unfortunately, we supposed to use Unary Pull Java API in reading the messages :-(

Thanks in advance.

We have tried encoding (base64) Unary Pull API and StreamPull API results (messages bytes) and compared it but results are not same for both the types.